# Getting error assignable to parameter of type

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am using "rxjs": "~6.2.0" in below code block

```
    canActivate():Observable<boolean>
     {
      return this.auth.user$.pipe
      (
        switchMap( 
                 user => 
                   {
                   return this.userService.get(user.uid);
                   }
                 )
       ).pipe( map( appUser => appUser.isAdmin))
     }
```

The get method of userService has below logic.

```
    get(uid : string): AngularFireObject<AppUser>
      {
        return this.db.object('/users/'+ uid);
      }
```

I am getting error

> "Argument of type '(user: User) => AngularFireObject' is not
>   assignable to parameter of type '(value: User, index: number) =>
>   ObservableInput'.   Type 'AngularFireObject' is not
>   assignable to type 'ObservableInput'.
>       Type 'AngularFireObject' is not assignable to type 'Iterable'.
>         Property '[Symbol.iterator]' is missing in type 'AngularFireObject'."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need not use two pipes here, `map` the result `appUser.isAdmin` using the same pipe.

```
canActivate():Observable<boolean>
{
      return this.auth.user$
       .pipe(
           switchMap(user => this.userService.get(user.uid)), 
           map(appUser => appUser.isAdmin)
       )
}
```

Also you should modify `userService.get()` to return proper `Observable` which you get from `valueChanges()`

```
get(uid : string): Observable<any>
{
     return this.db.object('/users/'+ uid).valueChanges();
}
```

Comment: Hi Amit, thank you for help.but I'm getting same error in switchmap . Can you please help me in this? Here the logic I want to achieve is switchmap should map user to appUser which we get from userService.then map additional property isAdmin to appUser.

Comment: Can you add more code? Probably `UserService` class as well.

Comment: Here is userService get method code.               get(uid : string): AngularFireObject<AppUser>
          {
            return this.db.object('/users/'+ uid);
          }

Comment: Why don't you return `return this.db.object('/users/'+ uid).valueChanges();` from `get()` method and declare its return type as `Observable<AppUser>`

Comment: Thank you Amit, but I am getting error in this "Type 'Observable<{}>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<AppUser>'.
  Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'AppUser'.
    Property 'name' is missing in type '{}'."

Comment: And if you do it as `Observable<any>`?

Answer (score 0):

The argument passed to `SwitchMap` should be an `Observable`, but `this.userService.get(user.uid)` returns a `AngularFireObject<AppUser>`.

`AngularFireObject` is from AngularFire. I haven't used AngularFire, but from what I get you have to call `valueChanges()` on the `AngularFireObject` in order to get an `Observer`. So if you can change the UserService, it should look like this:

```
get(uid : string): Observable<AppUser>
{
    return this.db.object('/users/'+ uid).valueChanges();
}
```

And as Amit Chigadani mentioned, you should put the switchMap and map in the same pipe, as well as simplifying the arrow function in the switchMap.

Comment: Thank you for help Amit provided answer.